# Graceful shutdown spring boot(After completeing queued requests)

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot application running on production server.

Now I want to kill the spring boot application but want to make sure that all the queued requests / requests which are still in processing state gets completed?

So can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using standalone or embedded (tomcat/jetty) container?

Comment: Embedded tomcat container(jar with app & tomcat)

Comment: There is a similar question which I have replied https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570089/how-to-wait-on-resttemplate-responses-on-shutdown